# proof Lemma which based on Fixpoint definitions

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, proof-general

Trying to prove following Lemma:

I have tried unfold nth_error and nth in the goal but I cannot figure out a way to tell Coq to break the Fixpoint definition of these two functions. I have also tried to induction on n and the lists but none of them was able to solve the problem since the items in list are irrelevant with each other. But this is obviously a correct Lemma, right now I feel it is un-provable, anyone can help me solve this problem? Much appreciated!

```
Lemma nth_error_nth :
  forall nodes1 (node : node) n,
    n < length nodes1 ->
    nth_error nodes1 n = Some (nth n nodes1 node).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question should really be edited to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we don't need to guess what definitions you're using. I'm assuming you're using the standard library's `List` module and that `node` is simply some type. Without any more information, I'll just assume it's something like `Variable node: Type`.

---

To prove this lemma, induction on the list itself should work. You'll probably also need to do case analysis on `n` (try `destruct n`) since `n_th` and a few other things depend on whether `n` is `0` or not. If something seems like it might be impossible to prove, try strengthening the inductive hypothesis. This involves having more hypotheses in the goal when you use `induction`. You can accomplish this with `revert` or simply never `intro` the hypothesis in question.

You'll likely get some absurd hypotheses, like n < 0. You can use some the lemmas in `PeanoNat.Nat` to derive a contradiction from this. It might be helpful to use the `Search` vernacular. For example, `Search (?n < 0).` finds the lemma I referred to. There's also one step where you'll need to conclude `m < n` from `S m < S n`, which can be done with `Lt.lt_S_n`.

Just to get you started, here's the beginning of a proof.

```
Lemma nth_error_nth :
  forall nodes1 (node : node) n,
    n < (length nodes1) ->
    nth_error nodes1 n = Some (nth n nodes1 node).
Proof.
  (* we don't intro n since we'll need to apply
     the inductive hypothesis to two different values of n *)
  intros nodes1 node.
  induction nodes1 as [ | a nodes1 IH].
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry about the code snippet that I posted which confused you. I have done proof with your method and I think I leaned a lot from your idea.

Comment: Note that `SearchAbout` is [deprecated](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/vernacular-commands.html#coq:cmdv.searchabout) since 8.5 in favor of `Search`.

Comment: @eponier hmmm, could have sworn there was still a difference. I guess not!